# Use bash's read builtin without a while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, subshell, read

I'm used to `bash`'s builtin `read` function in while loops, e.g.:

```
echo "0 1
      1 1
      1 2
      2 3" |\
while read A B; do
    echo $A + $B | bc;
done
```

I've been working on some `make` project, and it became prudent to split files and store intermediary results. As a consequence I often end up shredding single lines into variables. While the following example works pretty well,

```
head -n1 somefile | while read A B C D E FOO; do [... use vars here ...]; done
```

it's sort of stupid, because the while loop will never run more than once. But without the `while`,

```
head -n1 somefile | read A B C D E FOO; [... use vars here ...]
```

The read variables are always empty when I use them. I never noticed this behaviour of `read`, because usually I'd use while loops to process many similar lines. How can I use `bash`'s `read` builtin without a while loop? Or is there another (or even better) way to read a single line into multiple (!) variables?

**Conclusion**

The answers teach us, it's a problem of scoping. The statement

```
 cmd0; cmd1; cmd2 | cmd3; cmd4
```

is interpreted such that the commands `cmd0`, `cmd1`, and `cmd4` are executed in the same scope, while the commands `cmd2` and `cmd3` are each given their own subshell, and consequently different scopes. The original shell is the parent of both subshells.

Comment: Regarding your **Conclusion**: (1) The command line as originally presented is syntactically incorrect. Specifically, `… cmd1; | cmd2 …` is an error. (2) We can tell that `cmd2` and `cmd3` are each given their own subshell in `cmd1; cmd2 | cmd3; cmd4` by trying things like `answer=42 | sleep 0` or `cd other/dir | read foo`. You'll see that the first command in each pipeline must be in a subshell, as they do not effect the main (parent) shell process.

Comment: Incidentally, [you don't need to backslash escape a newline after a pipe character](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253520/135943).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the part where you use the vars is a new set of commands. Use this instead:

```
head somefile | { read A B C D E FOO; echo $A $B $C $D $E $FOO; }
```

Note that, in this syntax, there must be a space after the `{`
and a `;` (semicolon) before the `}`. 
Also `-n1` is not necessary; `read` only reads the first line.

For better understanding, this may help you; it does the same as above:

```
read A B C D E FOO < <(head somefile); echo $A $B $C $D $E $FOO
```

**Edit:**

It's often said that the next two statements do the same:

```
head somefile | read A B C D E FOO
read A B C D E FOO < <(head somefile)
```

Well, not exactly. The first one is a pipe from `head` to `bash`'s `read` builtin. One process's stdout to another process's stdin.

The second statement is redirection and process substitution. It is handled by `bash` itself. It creates a FIFO (named pipe, `<(...)`) that `head`'s output is connected to, and redirects (`<`) it to the `read` process.

So far these seem equivalent. But when working with variables it can matter. In the first one the variables are not set after executing. In the second one they are available in the current environment.

Every shell has another behavior in this situation. See [that link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for which they are. In `bash` you can work around that behavior with command grouping `{}`, process substitution (`< <()`) or Here strings (`<<<`).

Comment: `{}` ... I only tried `()`. Why does the `;` in your second example not start "a new set of commands"? Actually I don't understand the `< <` construct at all. Need to think ...

Comment: @Bananguin see my edit, hope it brings light to that problem.

Comment: I think I got it: The actual point is that WHEN USING PIPES, bash creates subshells for each processes of the pipeline, and due to scoping the variables are gone, after the pipeline. Using `{}` makes the remainder of the line an (one!) element of the pipeline, while inside that subshell the variables are available. Using process substitution one is not using pipes and therefore `bash` does not spawn subshells.

Comment: @Bananguin you got it ^^

Comment: Since `read` only reads the first line of input, it is not just `-n1` which is redundant but the entire `head` command. If you eliminate the `head` command, you can also eliminate the pipeline. Then it becomes `read A B C D E FOO < somefile` and it won't be a subshell, so the variables will remain available for the next command.

Comment: @kasperd: i use head as simple exemplarisch. Usually the heads are greps.

Comment: @Bananguin: `head somefile | ( read A B; echo $((A+B)) )` works, too. It uses `(…)` instead of `{ …;}`, and `bash`'s built-in arithmetic capability instead of `bc`.

Comment: @Scott: ad edit of my question. are you sure removing the pipe symbol does not make the the last paragraph false ...?

Answer (score 3):

To quote from a very useful article [wiki.bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read):

> This is because the commands of the pipe run in subshells that cannot modify the parent shell. As a result, the variables of the parent shell are not modified (see article: [Bash and the process tree](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/processtree)).

As the answer has been provided a few times now, an alternative way (using non builtin commands...) is this:

```
$ eval `echo 0 1 | awk '{print "A="$1";B="$2}'`;echo $B $A
$ 1 0
```

Comment: My problem was that I thought bash would put everything between the pipe symbol and the end of the line into the same subshell, but apparently it only reads the next statement.

Comment: Great question...

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the problem was that a pipe to `read` is run in a subshell.

One answer is to use a *heredoc*:

```
numbers="01 02"
read first second <<INPUT
$numbers
INPUT
echo $first
echo $second
```

This method is nice in that it will behave the same way in any POSIX-like shell.